# Noise recognition in Powershell

Tags: powershell, audio-recording, datatrigger

I want to collect the activity times from a machine which has no Interfaces to record the running Actions via wire. But I could put a PC with microphone close to that machine and listen to the microphone. If a certain noise Level is reached would indicate the activity, then record the timestamp until noise disappears.

Does anyone have an idea whether this is possible in Powershell and how to do it?

Comment: are you looking to check a machines activity based on the sound of the fans? this doesn't sound like it would be a great solution honestly. can you run the script on that machine to just check CPU usage, and save the results onto a USB when you need them?

Comment: How do you see this working? I mean, the mic would pick up every sound, so how would you differentiate sounds?

Comment: @ConnorLSW: the "machine" is not a PC, it's a huge, old heating unit :-)

Comment: @Snak3d0c: That's a matter of the threshold: The location of the machine is very silent if it's OFF and very noisy when turned on.
Believe me, if there's a way to script this, that would be sufficient enough to calculate the runtime.

Comment: @MMAX you won't find a process-audio cmdlet, you might be better off looking for how to do this in C# (i'm assuming [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196939/c-sharp-how-to-get-audio-decibel-values-with-time-span) might help) and looking at converting it to PS, this definitely won't be straightforward though.

Comment: @all: Thanks for your ideas. C# would probably do the trick but is definitely out of my scope.